# php artisan migrate could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

Ошибка после выполнения php artisan migrate в консоли IDE:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка после выполнения php artisan migrate в терминале wsl2:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую: phpstorm, wsl2(ubuntu20-04), docker, php8.1, laravel 9.

Перерыл что попало, перепробовал что попало, ничего не работает. Php.ini во всех возможных местах писал extension=pdo_mysql, extension=php_pdo_mysql, ребутал, переустанавливал php, php-mysql...

Так же попробовал сделать тестовую таблицу, занес туда результаты. Спокойно подключилось через mysqli_connect, сделал выборку/распечатку через mysqli_query/mysqli_fetch_all без ошибок.

Не понимаю в чем дело при artisan migrate :(

Comment: Неверно указано подключение к MySql или БД не доступна

Comment: Всё верно, mysqli работает. Ладно, я нашел решение...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php artisan migrate не работает из wsl консоли или из консоли ide...
Нужно открывать консоль основного контейнера из docker desctop (CLI):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И там всё сработает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но как я должен был это понять я не знаю, 2 дня потратил на это...

Comment: Ну это нормально что не работало из обычной консоли. У вас база находится в докер контейнере и чтобы делать какие-то манипуляции всегда нужно из консоли контейнера делать или в dockerfie

Comment: Остальные команды просто работают и в других терминалах, типа artisan make... Вот и не додумался что дело в этом ._.

Comment: `getaddrinfo` должна подсказать что name резолвинг не работает. И это прямой путь - а правильно ли указано, и где я это запускаю.